# Making an HTTP request on a data:application URL

Tags: node.js, csv, httprequest

I'm trying to make an HTTP request in Node on a data:application URL that gets generated, then writing the results

```
var fileName = "csv-" + uuid() + ".csv";
var fileLocation = process.env.USERPROFILE + "\\" + fileName;

var file=fs.createWriteStream(fileLocation);

var exportCsvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data);

var options={
    host: location.hostname,
    port: location.port,
    path: '/' + exportCsvData
}

console.log(exportCsvData);

http.get(options, function(response) {
    // write all of our message parts to the file
    response.pipe(file);
});
```

The file gets created, but the only thing that is written is "Not Found". However when I take the `exportCsvData` data that gets logged out, then copy and paste it into Chrome, it downloads the data just fine.

I've also tried doing

```
http.get(options,function(res){
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            file.write(chunk);
        });
        res.on('end',function(){
            file.end();
        });
    });
```

With the same result.

Edit: I've just realized that in this specific case, I can just grab `data` and write that out to a csv file and it will work just fine.